# baseball-almanac.com API returning 403 error

Tags: python, api, anaconda, spyder, screen-scraping

I am a complete noob to API and web scraping. I am trying to recreate the example in chapter 5 of 'Learn to Code with Baseball'.

I am using Spyder (Python 3.8). First I import the following libraries:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame
```

Then, I type these next two statements

```
bal_response = requests.get('http://baseball-almanac.com/opening_day/odschedule.php?t=BAL')

print(bal_response.text)
```

This returns the following 403 error message

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /opening_day/odschedule.php
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here? I am literally following the book's steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Add the user-agent in the headers parameter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
bal_response = requests.get('http://baseball-almanac.com/opening_day/odschedule.php?t=BAL', headers=headers)
print(bal_response.text)
```